# Open Cv Python Code with bitwise operators for measuring mass of the green color

Tags: python, computer-vision, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How do I check the mass of green colour using `bitwise` operators in `opencv` Python?

I tried using the `cv2.inRange` function to create a mask that isolates the green colour in an image, and then calculates the mass of green colour by counting the number of non-zero pixels in the mask using the `cv2.countNonZero` function but I was expected to use `bitwise` operations.

Comment: Seems to me you are doing it the right way. I have no idea what your teacher was thinking. Maybe ask them how they want you to solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.